# Як правильно: кОгорта чи кАгорта?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники, орфографія

Знала, що правильно використовувати слово кОгорта. Про це свідчить і [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/koghorta):

> **КОГО́РТА**, и, жін.
>
> ***1. У стародавньому Римі — загін війська, що становив десяту частину легіону.*** На підмогу вігілам [військовій сторожі] прибігають вояки міської когорти і сяк-так утихомирюють люд, загрожуючи зброєю (Леся Українка, II, 1951, 530).
>
> ***2. перен., уроч. Згуртована спільними ідеями, цілями, прагненнями група людей.*** — Свирид Гордійович належить до тієї когорти мужніх, які на власних плечах наше село в колективізацію вносили (Микола Руденко, Остання шабля, 1959, 209).

Однак випадково натрапила на статтю Ярослава Матвіїшина ["НАУКОВО-ПЕДАГОГІЧНА ДІЯЛЬНІСТЬ ІРИНЕЯ ФАЛЬКІВСЬКОГО В ГАЛУЗІ АСТРОНОМІЇ"](http://www.iapmm.lviv.ua/12/ukr_sky/ukr_sky-1/data/606-654.pdf), в якій автор використовує це слово дещо інакше:

> [...] належить до **кагорти** славних представників нашої культури й науки  порубіжжя XVII та XVIIІ ст.

То як же все-таки правильно, **к*О*горта** чи **к*А*горта**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Справдї, ненаголошене **о** може наближати ся до звуку **а**, порівняйте: білоруська *каго́рта*, московська *кого́рта*, де ненаголошене **о** звучить як **а**. Тому для цього [правопис](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par1) навіть має правила:

> **§ 1. Ненаголошений *О***
>
> 1. У складах із ненаголошеним **о** пишеться та сама літера (буква) **о**, що й під наголосом: *бої́ться* (бо *бо́язко*), *голу́бка* (бо *го́луб*); *дощу́* (бо *до́щ*), *робі́ть* (бо *ро́бить*), *розу́мний* (бо *ро́зум*).
>
>    **О** пишеться й у таких словах, де сумнівний із правописного погляду звук наголосом не перевіряється: *лопу́х*, *соки́ра*, *сою́з*.
> 2. У деяких словах на місці **о** перед постійно наголошеним **а** (**я**) маємо у вимові й на письмі **а**: *бага́тий*, *бага́то*, *бага́тство*, *бага́ття*, *бага́ч*, *гаря́чий*, *гаря́чка* (пор. *горіти*), *гара́зд*, *кажа́н*, *кала́ч*, *кача́н*, *хазя́їн*, а також у деяких похідних з іншим наголосом: *бага́тир* (багач), *га́ряче́*; але: *гонча́р*, *коря́вий*, *лопа́та*, *пога́ний*, *ропа́*, *солда́т*, *това́р*, а також *богати́р* (велетень, герой), *монасти́р*.

Котре не допоможе. А ось [етимологічний словник](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom2.pdf#page=488) допоможе:

> *Мій переказ.* Слово походить від лятинького *cohors* »когорта (підроздїл леґіону)«, де:
>
> - *hors* > *hortus* »обгороджене місце; город; сідок; (ст.) вілла«; словʼянське *город* тут споріднене;
> - *co-* приросток »з-«, котрий і наразї вельми чудово ся почуває (*коаліція*, *комо́д*, *коло́нія* тощо).

Як знаємо, українська вельми [любить зберігати](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par89) чужомовні приростки без змін. Тому [словники](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=42595) правильно вказують, що через **о** — **кого́рта**.